Flink JDBC Exactly Once sink terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout error
I have a Flink pipeline which has two sinks , one sink to publish messages to Kafka and other to update the status in database. I am following exactly once semantics using Kafka transaction and XA JDBC transaction.
I am facing below issue in JDBC sink.
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 update public.event_log set event_status = 'SUCCESS' where id = ('xxx') was abort
ed: FATAL: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

I googled and found that we need to disable the below properties which I did but still getting the same error.
#idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0    # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#idle_session_timeout = 0       # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
checkpointing interval set to 1 min , kafka transaction timeout set to 1.5 mins , parallelism to 3.
Context on sinks:
keyedEventLog stream gets input from JDBC source and is then transformed to kafkaPRoducerRecordStream to be used by Kafka Sink.
Kafka Sink
 CustomKafkaUtil.writeRecords(kafkaProducerRecordStream, writeConfig, StringSerializer::new, "oiwp-event-log");

Custom Kafka Util class

CustomKafkaUtil extends KafkaUtil {

    public static <V> void writeRecords(DataStream<KafkaProducerRecord<byte[], V>> producerRecords, EventbusWriteRuntimeConf writeConfig, SerializableSupplier<Serializer<V>> serializerSupplier, String uidSuffix) {
        uidSuffix = uidSuffix != null ? uidSuffix : writeConfig.topic;
        producerRecords
                .sinkTo(getCustomSink(writeConfig))
                .name("kafka-sink-" + uidSuffix)
                .uid("kafka-sink-" + uidSuffix);
    }

    private static KafkaSink<Object> getCustomSink(EventbusWriteRuntimeConf writeConfig) {
        String topic = writeConfig.topic;
        Properties producerProperties = SppConfigUtil.instance.getKafkaProducerConfig(topic, writeConfig.cluster, writeConfig.region);
        if (!writeConfig.kafkaProperties.isEmpty()) {
            producerProperties.putAll(writeConfig.kafkaProperties);
        }
        log.info("producer properties: {}", producerProperties);
        return getSinkBuilder(producerProperties)
                .setRecordSerializer(new KafkaRecordSerializationSchema<Object>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5597069351310493251L;

                    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(Object element, KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.KafkaSinkContext context, Long timestamp) {
                        KafkaProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> kafkaRecord = (KafkaProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>) element;
                        return new ProducerRecord<>(kafkaRecord.topic, kafkaRecord.partition, kafkaRecord.timestamp, kafkaRecord.key, kafkaRecord.value, KafkaUtil.getRecordHeaders(kafkaRecord.headers));
                    }
                })
                .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
                .setTransactionalIdPrefix("oiwp-kafka-sink-random")
                .build();
    }
}


JDBC Sink
           keyedEventLogRecord.addSink(
                        JdbcSink.exactlyOnceSink(
                                "update " + applicationConfig.getDbConfig().getSchema() + "." + "event_log " + "set event_status = 'SUCCESS' where id = ?",
                                ((preparedStatement, row) -> {
                                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                    JsonNode jsonNode = null;
                                    try {
                                        jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(row.f0);
                                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                                    preparedStatement.setString(1, jsonNode.get("id").asText());
                                }),
                                JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
                                        .withMaxRetries(0)
                                        .build(),
                                JdbcExactlyOnceOptions.builder().withAllowOutOfOrderCommits(false)
                                        .withTransactionPerConnection(true)
                                        .build(),
                                new PGXADataSourceProvider(
                                        applicationConfig.getDbConfig().getJdbcUrl() + "/" + applicationConfig.getDbConfig().getDatabase(),
                                        applicationConfig.getDbConfig().getUsername(),
                                        applicationConfig.getDbConfig().getPassword()
                                ))).name("oiwp-event-log-jdbc-sink").uid("oiwp-event-log-jdbc-sink");

Dependencies
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required for connecting to JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.2</version>
        </dependency>

